# How do I know when I'm done with Her Story?

Tags: her-story

Is there any sort of end or "victory" to this game, or is it meant to simply end when you feel you've satisfied your own curiosity about what happened and stop playing?

Answer (score 3):

As @TheForestAndTheTrees pointed out, you get a message from 'SB' once you're halfway done.

Once you've seen the credits at least once, you'll be given hints for two commands.  One of these hidden commands unlocks a "program" that shows you a bunch of squares that represent which videos you've seen and which you haven't... and which order they appear in.

Once you unlock it, the icon for launching this program is hidden behind the video search window.

Even after you see 100% of the videos, there's still no real ending.  Which makes sense as you're supposed to figure out what really happened on your own.

Comment: On a side note, after I 100%ed the game, I found the videos in the Steam directory (which are sorted in order) and watched them.  The story tends to make a bit more sense, but there are still a few unexplained things even then...

Comment: I think the program you're talking about was there even before I watched the credits.

Comment: The program is there from the begining

Answer (score 2):

After you've uncovered 50% of the videos, you'll get a message from 'SB', asking you whether you're done. If you enter Yes, you'll exit the game and get a very short reveal and the end credits.

If you entered No, you can recall 'SB' afterwards and say you're done again.